# How To Add Files or Directory ClickOnce Deployment

Tags: c#, clickonce

In my project I have a directory that's holding my Report files. When I deploy it to localhost, it's not including this directory. So with a little research I found a solution. I then added a directory to my project in VS and make my report file Build Action Content, Copy Output to Directory property. Now when I publish it, I can see my Reports folder in ClickOnce deploy.

But now it's saying that `xcvqw34asdasczxcasdasdasd.3asd\Reports\generalReport.frx` is not found, when within my code I call it `Reports\\generalReport.frx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected the problem. I changed

```
Reports\\generalReport.frx
```

to:

```
.\\Raporlar\\genelRapor.frx
```